# Nucleotide Count

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, unit-testing

I am learning Java and hence practicing it from [here](http://exercism.io/exercises/java/nucleotide-count/readme). The solution seems pretty trivial to me but still I would like to have a honest review which would guide me to following ideas:

1. Am I maintaining class Invariants?
2. Do I need to have more **Domain** specific error messages?
3. Although the solution seems trivial but I am missing some performance boost?
4. Am I following proper encapsulation?
5. Using correct data structures?
6. Any other suggestion are most welcome.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Collections;

public class DNA {
  private final Map<Character, Integer> nucleotideMap = new HashMap<>();
  private final String dnaSequence;

  public DNA(String dnaSequence) {
    this.dnaSequence = dnaSequence;
    initializeDefaultNucleotideMap();
    if (!dnaSequence.isEmpty()) {
      countNucleotides();
    }
  }

  private Map<Character, Integer> initializeDefaultNucleotideMap() {
    nucleotideMap.put('A', 0);
    nucleotideMap.put('C', 0);
    nucleotideMap.put('G', 0);
    nucleotideMap.put('T', 0);
    return nucleotideMap;
  }

  private void countNucleotides() {
    for (Character chr : dnaSequence.toCharArray()) {
      nucleotideMap.put(chr, nucleotideMap.get(chr) + 1);
    }
  }

  public int count(char nucleotide) {
    if (!nucleotideMap.containsKey(nucleotide)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid nucleotide");
    }
    return nucleotideMap.get(nucleotide);
  }

  public Map<Character, Integer> nucleotideCounts() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(nucleotideMap);
  }
}
```

Test suites:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.entry;

import org.junit.Test;

public class NucleotideTest {
  @Test
  public void testEmptyDnaStringHasNoAdenosine() {
    DNA dna = new DNA("");
    assertThat(dna.count('A')).isEqualTo(0);
  }

  @Test
  public void testEmptyDnaStringHasNoNucleotides() {
    DNA dna = new DNA("");
    assertThat(dna.nucleotideCounts()).hasSize(4).contains(
        entry('A', 0),
        entry('C', 0),
        entry('G', 0),
        entry('T', 0)
    );
  }

  @Test
  public void testRepetitiveCytidineGetsCounted() {
    DNA dna = new DNA("CCCCC");
    assertThat(dna.count('C')).isEqualTo(5);
  }

  @Test
  public void testRepetitiveSequenceWithOnlyGuanosine() {
    DNA dna = new DNA("GGGGGGGG");
    assertThat(dna.nucleotideCounts()).hasSize(4).contains(
        entry('A', 0),
        entry('C', 0),
        entry('G', 8),
        entry('T', 0)
    );
  }

  @Test
  public void testCountsOnlyThymidine() {
    DNA dna = new DNA("GGGGGTAACCCGG");
    assertThat(dna.count('T')).isEqualTo(1);
  }

  @Test
  public void testCountsANucleotideOnlyOnce() {
    DNA dna = new DNA("CGATTGGG");
    dna.count('T');
    assertThat(dna.count('T')).isEqualTo(2);
  }

  @Test
  public void testDnaCountsDoNotChangeAfterCountingAdenosine() {
    DNA dna = new DNA("GATTACA");
    dna.count('A');
    assertThat(dna.nucleotideCounts()).hasSize(4).contains(
        entry('A', 3),
        entry('C', 1),
        entry('G', 1),
        entry('T', 2)
    );
  }

  @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void testValidatesNucleotides() {
    DNA dna = new DNA("GACT");
    dna.count('X');
  }

  @Test
  public void testCountsAllNucleotides() {
    String s = "AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC";
    DNA dna = new DNA(s);
    assertThat(dna.nucleotideCounts()).hasSize(4).contains(
        entry('A', 20),
        entry('C', 12),
        entry('G', 17),
        entry('T', 21)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Mast so how would you proceed if you needed to write it as a production level code? should there be a distinction between a code for review here and a production level code? Are we here to review just the toy code?

Comment: Funny you should ask, I put something similar written in Ruby [up for review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115504/count-the-occurence-of-nucleobases-in-dna-string) not too long ago.

Comment: @Mast its because the exercism team took the reference from that site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I maintaining class Invariants?

Yes. But I wonder if you really need to expose `nucleotideCounts`. You did it safely, by wrapping the map in `unmodifiableMap` (and because the values are immutable too). To eliminate the risk of abuses and errors, it would be better to keep this implementation detail hidden.

> Do I need to have more Domain specific error messages?

I don't see an obvious reason to do that. The `IllegalArgumentException` seems appropriate when trying to get an invalid nucleotide.

> Although the solution seems trivial but I am missing some performance boost?

Since the number of nucleotides is unlikely to change, using a `Map` for the storage seems a bit overkill. A simple array of 4 elements would be more light-weight. That being said, premature optimization is considered evil, so I wouldn't worry about this too much until the current implementation is proven to be a bottleneck.

> Am I following proper encapsulation?

As mentioned earlier, it would be better to hide the implementation detail of the storage of the nucleotide counts, that is, remove the `nucleotideCounts` method. But it depends on your use case. If you really need that method, then you cannot remove it. In any case, it's important to ask that question: *should this be hidden?*

> Using correct data structures?

Yes.

> Any other suggestion are most welcome.

Some additional tips and observations:

1. No need to keep `dnaSequence` in a field. Once you built the map of counts from it, you no longer need it. I suggest to get rid of it.
2. In the constructor, it's unnecessary to check if `dnaSequence` is empty. The iteration logic in `countNucleotides` naturally embeds that check.
3. You'll get an NPE on invalid nucleotides, for example `new DNA("hello")`

Comment: exposing `nucleotideCounts` was the part of the exercise to pass the tests. Although your recommendation seems valuable to me.

Comment: regarding the third point, I need to put that check in my constructor. Something, with a method like `checkPrecondtion` or `validateArguments` right?

Comment: you could have a `validateNucleotide(char)` method, that throws if invalid. You could call this method from `count` and also from the loop in `countNucleotides`

Comment: One more thing, its said that we shouldn't do any work in constructor apart from initializing fields to their default values, but here I need to do some computation, is this right strategy?

Comment: Building the data structure is the purpose of this class. So it's a well justified exception to the general rule to avoid computation in the constructor.

Comment: Just in case there is a requirement in which client needs to know all the `nucleotides` with their counts then it would be needed somehow to give that data to client. What should we do in that case? then in that case I would break encapsulation, right?

Comment: That's what I tried to explained in *"If you really need that method, then you cannot remove it"*. So in your case, you're not breaking encapsulation: you're simply fulfilling your client requirements by providing that method.

Comment: @CodeYogi In your case you are already doing some computation in your constructor, it's just that you are calling some private methods to perform the computation, but those methods are still called from the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

#### Don't expose too much

You currently have a method `nucleotideCounts` that returns the map of each nucleotide with its count in the DNA sequence. But do you really need this method? It is very correctly implemented by returning an unmodifiable map, but I would argue that you should remove the method completely.

So far, your DNA class is keeping track of the count of nucleotide through a map. But this is internal information / an implementation detail. A client of `DNA` does not need to know how the count is being maintained. The logic of operating with a DNA sequence should go through the `DNA` class itself, because it is responsible for that. This is the goal of object-oriented programming: having an object responsible for a specific task.

As an example, currently, if a client needs to know if a `DNA` contains a specific nucleotide, they need to do:

```
boolean hasA = dna.nucleotideCounts().containsKey('A');
```

Instead, consider creating a method `hasNucleotide` inside the class `DNA`:

```
public boolean hasNucleotide(char nucleotide) {
    return nucleotideMap.containsKey(nucleotide);
}
```

Then a client can call `boolean hasA = dna.hasNucleotide('a');` without getting a reference to the internal data structure being used.

Of course, implementing this now requires you, the `DNA` class maintainer, to know what kind of methods you will want to add and support (at least as a start, you can of course add methods later).

In my view, this is the most important comment.

#### Remove redundant checks

In your constructor, you are doing

```
if (!dnaSequence.isEmpty()) {
    countNucleotides();
}
```

but the `if` is not really needed since in the case of an empty DNA sequence, nothing will happen inside the `countNucleotides()` method. Might as well simplify the code and remove the check.

#### Beware of `null`

You are not checking whether the given `dnaSequence` in the constructor of `DNA` is `null`. With your current code, if you give `null` then it will fail with a `NullPointerException`.

This could be a wanted behaviour. Some JDK classes also follow this convention. However, if this is indeed wanted then it is best to document it properly in the constructor's Javadoc.

Worth mentioning, with Java 7, you could use [`requireNonNull(obj, message)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-) to throw an exception if the given object is null with the given message.

Comment: Note that `containsKey('A')` on the `Map` will currently always return true, as ACGT are all initialized to `0` in the map.

Answer (score 2):

Enum, an enum, <strike>my kingdom for an enum!</strike> an answer about an enum!

As far as I know, there are always four different nucleotide types. A, C, G, T. What do programmers do when there is always a limited amount of something? They make an `enum`.

```
public enum NucleotideType {
    A, C, G, T;
}
```

By using this little type as a key in your map, so that you have `Map<NucleotideType, Integer>`, you can handle your class in better ways. (See the tips provided by Tunaki and Janos).

In fact, even better would be to use an [`EnumMap<NucleotideType, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) which would likely offer a performance-boost.

Comment: Hmm, I see, It would also let me write more domain specific code, right?

Comment: What would happen if the client needs to call `count('A')`? where and how this conversion from char to enum takes place? If I am not asking too much, can you please put an example, please?

Comment: I think this would help me http://stackoverflow.com/a/604426/4260745

Comment: @CodeYogi an Enum is still a class, you can add a static method to convert a char to your enum. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2965252/2115680 ( you posted your comment at the same time)

Comment: @CodeYogi You would refer to the `'A'` as `NucleotideType.A`

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2781d2ce4dd5dd731971395e9bbfbcd0) is the idea, I hope its fine.

Comment: @CodeYogi Yeah, that looks quite fine to me